# ¿Cómo debo usar setImageAlpha para hacer que una imagen sea transparente en Android Studio?

Tags: onclick

Quiero que una imagen de la activity se vuelva transparente con una acción OnClick, no lo puedo hacer añadiendo atributo porque quiero que al darle click a la imagen se haga transparente con el OnClick.
Entonces hay un comando que se llama setImageAlpha(int), lo malo es que está limitado, porque solo puedo poner 0 o 1, con 0 no se ve porque se queda en 0% y con 1 se queda al 100%, ¿existirá algún comando parecido a setImageAlpha(int), pero que sea con un valor float? Necesito un comando en el que la transparencia pueda ser libre, porque quiero un 60% de transparencia. Esa es mi pregunta.

---

Ok me olvidé de algo, existe el comando setAlpha(), en el cual puse setAlpha(60) y pensé que ya podría funcionar, pero luego a ese comando se transformó a un texto tachado y me salió un mensaje emergente: "setAlpha(int) is deprecated as of API 16: Android Jelly Bean (4.0)" En mi proyecto estoy usando API 20 y me dice que el comando es obsoleto, ¿lo puedo usar igual o no funcionará? Lo veré al compilar.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilices el comando setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) o (View.INVISIBLE)
Yo lo utilizo para mostrar o no ciertos botones segun seleccion.
Pero si no lo quieres totalmente transparente, puedes utilizar el bakground del selector de color para hacerlo mas o menos transparente. O cambiar la imagen por otra mas ligera como si lo fuera.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó más o menos así, hice una copia de la imagen la cuál tiene ya el atributo de transparencia y el atributo de invisible, el onClick hace que se alternen las 2 imagenes con el comando setVisibility, gracias.